# Can I run WeBots from Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter, webots

I am reading through Webots official tutorials, and I see they use their IDE, Pycharm etc. But can I use Jupyter? I like Jupyter's ability to run code block-by-block...
I see examples in the net, but they are ready to use simulators, while I want to understand how to install and configure the thing.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Webots has its own code editor for coding the robot controller. We can use other IDEs when writing our code but we cannot run from those IDEs as Webots has its own libraries like the Robot nodes.

If we use an IDE to write the code one of the advantages that we get is that we can reduce the typos that we get when we type the controller code. The method I follow is that I write the code on the separate IDE and I simulate the code in Webots code editor to see if the code is working correctly in Webots.